# Should package.json be included in .prettierignore file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, prettier

Configuring Prettier for the first time and I understand that things like build/deploy files and node_modules (obviously) should be ignored, as well as auto-generated files like package-lock.json.  What about package.json?  It's partially auto generated but people also go in and edit it manually, so I think there is value in running Prettier on it.  Any other best practices for what to include/not include in the ignore file?  I'm assuming submodules should be left in once Prettier has been run on the submodule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommended to allow prettier and other linters to read/lint package.json.

You want to keep things tidy and consistent. Rule of thumb is if it's not autogenerated then go ahead.